# Add date stamp on uploaded file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently developing a website using asp and c#. One of the pages allows registered users to upload files. These files get stored according to the user who is logged in. A directory is created when they hit upload with there login name and id.

```
string userDirectory = "\\Test\\Files\\ " + User.Identity.Name + " " + User.Identity.GetUserId();
if (!Directory.Exists(userDirectory))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(userDirectory);
        }
```

The directory gets created without an issue and file also gets uploaded. However the problem I am now facing is I'm trying to add a date stamp to a file if it already exist in the directory so I don't overwrite it. See the code below

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(userDirectory, FileUpload1.FileName);
if (!File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileName);
        }
        else
        {
            fileName = string.Concat(
            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName),
            DateTime.Now.ToString("_yyyy_MM_dd_HH:mm:ss"),
            Path.GetExtension(fileName)
            );
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileName);
        }
```

This keeps giving me an error:

```
System.Web.HttpException: The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path 'Test.docx' is not rooted
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to append the directory name to the path, since you stripped it off (by using `GetFileNameWithoutExtension`):

```
string newFileName = 
    Path.Combine( Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName)
                , string.Concat( Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)
                               , DateTime.Now.ToString("_yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss")
                               , Path.GetExtension(fileName)
                               )
                );
```

Also note that using `:` in a file name is not supported, so I replace it with `_`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Now it gives me the following error `System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.`

Comment: @user4079043: I already updated my answer for that. I replaced `:` with `_`.